# Advanced pandas value_counts() with matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a website I manage and I have been applying data analytics with Pandas to get useful insights from my products and the companies that supply them.

Now on my website, there are tons of products there and I give each product an ID to identify each product that is produced by a Company, so that means a Company can have different products ie. productIDs.

On my site, you can compare products that meet your demands from different companies and I programmed my site to allow only three comparisons. You can only compare three products with various features at a time.

I have been able to setup google analytics to track the data. so for example with a diagram below: A customer compared `product IDs` `920` with `470` and `212` side by side.

[image]

I would like to perform `value_counts` independently for each product and then see which products were compared the most versus other products and have a  `Seaborn` or `matplotlib Group bar plot` like this?

[image]

Here is the `dataframe` for your convenience:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID_A': ['920','162','920','920','920','165','920'],
 'ProductID_B': ['470','470','470','212', np.nan,'470','470'],
 'ProductID_C': ['212','212',"212", "570",'212','1670', '212']})
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to melt the column. I also tried to do a countplot for each column, but I would like by each other not individual

Answer (score -1):

Does this achieve your desired result?

`df. unstack` pivots the original dataframe then `reset_index` is used to convert everything so it is not grouped anymore. The column names in the groupby are the default left from unstack but that could be changed or specified in your plot.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).reset_index()

df2 = df1[[0, 'level_0']].groupby(0).count()

sns.barplot(x= df2.index, y = 'level_0', data = df2)
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.xlabel('product ID')
```

[image]

Comment: No, this does not solve my problem, unfortunately. did you look at my plot in the description?

Comment: To clarify, you want the individual product id counts, e.g., for 920, 162, 470 etc?

Comment: I need a grouped bar plot of them side by side